# Bash script to disable root login

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to automate as much as possible in the deployment of servers, the overall goal is to  login as a user, upload a bashscript and have it configure my server how I need it configured.

To start I'm trying to disable root login, I know I have to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `PermitRootLogin no`

I was wondering if there was a way to do this via a bash script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to just append your text to the **sshd_config** file, you could use `printf` like this:

```
printf '\n%s\n' 'PermitRootLogin no' >>/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

or if you want to change a file that already have a value set, but you want to set it to **no**, could use `sed` like this:

```
sed -i '/^PermitRootLogin[ \t]\+\w\+$/{ s//PermitRootLogin no/g; }' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploy servers, you should use a tool for this. I remind you "Ansible". It will be easier (and more "elegant").

Here, you have a tutorial about how to disable root login with Ansible http://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/

I hope my answer will help you!